# FMU-modules and method get_author()

Tags: python, modelica, fmi, jmodelica

I use JModelica since many years and now run the current version 2.2. I am interested to share (compiled) FMU-modules and put my name and company into the FMU-module. If your FMU-module have the name model then there is a method model.get_author() that will bring that information. For the FMU-modules I do now I just get a blank result calling this method. How do put in information into my model? Is that possible for the current version of JModelica?

Comment: You should provide a programming language in tags, then it would be easier to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the current release of JModelica 2.2, it is not possible for a user to automatically include the author in the generated modelDescription file in the FMU.

Currently this has to be done manually by a user (i.e. unzip the FMU, updated the XML, and zip the FMU).